# Passing integer array to a c++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

C++ dll function declaration is

```
static void __clrcall BubbleSort(int* arrayToSort,int size);
```

My C++ dll function is

```
void Sort::BubbleSort(int* sortarray,int size)
    {
        int i,j;
        int temp=0;
       for(i=0; i< (size - 1); ++i)
        {
            for(j = i + 1; j > 0; --j)
            {
                if(sortarray[j] < sortarray[j-1])
                {
                    temp = sortarray[j];
                    sortarray[j] = sortarray[j - 1];
                    sortarray[j - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In C#, I am accesssing above function as

```
Sort.Sort.BubbleSort(arrayToBeSort,5);
```

But C sharp compiler gives error as

The best overloaded method match for 'Sort.Sort.BubbleSort(int*, int)' has some invalid arguments
and
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'int*'

Comment: How is `Sort.Sort.BubbleSort` declared in C# code

Comment: 1st Sort is namespace 2nd Sort is a class name

Comment: If you want help you need to show the C# declaration of `BubbleSort`.

Comment: C# declartion for bubble sortprivate void BtnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sort.Sort.BubbleSort(arrayToBeSort,5);
           
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                MessageBox.Show("" + arrayToBeSort[i]);
        }

Comment: No, that's where you call it. You haven't shown your declaration yet.

Comment: I did not have any declaration for Bubblesort in my C# code

Comment: Ah, OK. I guess the .net framework sorts that all out for you. Sorry, I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in managed C++ need to use the managed syntax.

```
static void __clrcall BubbleSort(array<int>^ arrayToSort, int size)
```

This translates in C# to

```
public static void BubbleSort(int[] array, int size);
```

Your declaration, instead matches the C# declaration using pointers (unsafe code).

```
public static void BubbleSort(int* array, int size);
```

If you need to pass a value by reference you should write something like this:

```
static void __clrcall MyFunc(array<int>^% arrayByReference)
```

Comment: How do i pass this array as a reference from C#

Comment: For this particular problem you don't need to, you can modify the content of the array in the bubble sort function without passing the array by reference.